# Split odd rows of DataFrame without double iloc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

Test `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,7,8,4],
                   'B':[4,5,6,1,4,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9,2,7,3],
                   'D':[4,5,2,1,0,6]})

df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)
print (df)
     C  D
A B      
1 4  7  4
2 5  8  5
3 6  9  2
7 1  2  1
8 4  7  0
4 6  3  6
```

Splitted by odd rows:

```
print (df.iloc[::2])
     C  D
A B      
1 4  7  4
3 6  9  2
8 4  7  0
```

I need split it again - last row in `df1` and all other rows to `df2`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[-2::2]
df2 = df.iloc[::2].iloc[:-1,:]

print (df1)
     C  D
A B      
8 4  7  0

print (df2)
     C  D
A B      
1 4  7  4
3 6  9  2
```

Is better solution without double [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
df2 = df.iloc[:-2:2]

     C  D
A B      
1 4  7  4
3 6  9  2
```

Comment: how to change it fro even rows ?

Comment: change starting index to 1, so df.iloc[1:-2:2]

Comment: You also need to change the end index e.g. df.iloc[1:-1:2]